# creating objects from a group of data or an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am really having trouble trying to put this together for some reason. anyone who can point me in the right direction. im sure im close just cant figure it out. my data is being created into an array with the code below. but what I really want is to make a nice object that contains the data for pieces,taken,top and left with their associated values attached. something nice and pretty looking

```
pieces.push(objdata[a])
taken.push(objdata[b])
top.push(objdata[c])
left.push(objdata[d])
```

http://jsfiddle.net/emz8snek/

my trouble isn't with object creation in general but with combining these arrays into an object. I have googled a lot in face the link eddie put up the first 2 pages ive looked at already.

Comment: super helpful. I have already googled my heart out. its all very either not what I need or way to complex for me.  I know how to make an object I just don't know how to make  4 arrays become a single object.

Comment: You can set the properties of an object to equal whatever you want when you create the object. Array items are no different. I don't understand what the problem is exactly because you haven't explained where you are getting stuck. You also haven't clarified what you want the object to look like.

Comment: eddie  you need to get some people don't know everything. I was unaware how easy it was to make an object with arrays like you said here. it was not covered in some of the sites that it could be done this way.  not everyone here posts complex questions. sometimes the answer is silly easy.

Comment: don't get me wrong, there's absolutely nothing wrong with posting questions with "silly easy" answers. But you didn't ask very clearly. While in this case someone guessed your intention, you didn't say that you wanted the arrays to simply be crammed into an object wholesale. You could have intended to organize your data in any number of ways. If you update your question with that information included I will remove my downvote.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you only want to create an object based on the array, do like this.

```
var objectExample = {
               piecesArray:pieces,
               takenArray:taken,
               topArray:top, 
               leftArray:left
    }

    console.log(objectExample);
```

Comment: This question is unanswerable cause OP didn't give enough information about what they want. If you don't understand the problem you shouldn't post an answer until OP clarifies.

Comment: `I just don't know how to make 4 arrays become a single object`, from user comment.

Comment: I knew it was much simpler than I was making it. I know it was a newbie question so I thank you for being so kind about it. ill mark it as answer when it lets me.